# dynamically generated elements not displaying on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I create some dynamically generated html by `jQuery` and then add some click event on this generated html.

The click event work fine and the code inside run correctly and add some anther dynamically generated html to the first dynamically generated html on the page.

So what I am trying  to do is first dynamically generated html then add click event on it after the click event is triggered, add some more dynamically generated html to the fist dynamically generated html.

This all works fine but the second dynamically generated html not displaying on the screen, I inspect element on the target html and the html was generated but still not displayed on the screen.

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {

console.log("Category Page Script loaded");

$.post('/Category/GetCategories', {}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    $Category = $('ul#Category-filter');
    $Category.empty();
    console.log("coustom empty");
    var html = '';

    for (sub in data) {
        console.log(data[sub].CategoryID, data[sub].CategoryName);
        var html = '<li class="dropdown-tree CategorySelected" data-id="' + data[sub].CategoryID + '">'
                   + '<a class="dropdown-tree-a">' + data[sub].CategoryName + ' COLLECTION </a>'
                   + '<ul class="category-level-2 dropdown-menu-tree" id="category">'
                   + '</ul>'
                   + '</li>'
        console.log(html);
        $Category.append(html);
    }

}).error(function () {
    console.log('error');
});
//___________________________________________________________________________

$(document).on('click', 'li.CategorySelected', function () {

    console.log("clickd");

    // Get the id from the link
    var SelectedCategoryID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(SelectedCategoryID);


    if (SelectedCategoryID != '') {

        console.log('1');

        $CategorySelected = $('#category');
        console.log($CategorySelected);
        console.log('2');
        $CategorySelected.empty();
        console.log('3');
        console.log("CategorySelected empty");
        console.log('4');
        var html = '';
        console.log('5');
        $.post("/SubCategory/GetSubCategories", { SelectedCategoryID: SelectedCategoryID },
         function (data) {
             console.log(data);
             console.log('6');
             for (sub in data) {
                 console.log(data[sub].SubCategoryID, data[sub].SubCategoryName);

                 var html = '<li><a href="' + data[sub].SubCategoryID + '">' + data[sub].SubCategoryName + ' </a> </li>'

                 console.log(html);

                 $CategorySelected.append(html);
                 console.log($CategorySelected);
             }


         });
    }
});

//_________________________________________________________
});
```

Comment: Please fix your question text. I have no idea what you are asking honestly

Comment: @ScottMitchell I honestly tried to edit it in to some kind of sense, but it broke me and I gave up.

Comment: OK just a sec and i will fix the question

Comment: @Fadi you asked already this question. Rory McCrossan left a comment, just follow that. 
change document by ul id.
$('ul#Category-filter').on('click', 'li.CategorySelected', function(){
    //your scripts here
});

Comment: it work for my first problem but now i have this second problem it  generated the html but not display it in the screen

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs only when parent element id is duplicate, please ensure that no dulipcate id is used for parent element.